How do I remove a redundant ibus keyboard layout indicator?
I use the Cinnamon desktop environment, v6.0.4, on Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur (~= Debian Trixie).
I use multiple keyboard layouts. On my taskbar, I see two distinct keyboard layout indicators, which identify themselves as:

iBus 1.5.30 "IBus is an intelligent input bus for Linux/Unix."
Keyboard (keyboard@cinnamon.org) "Keyboard Layout"

When I press the layout switch key combination, it's the Cinnamon indicator which changes; and that is ok with me. What I want is to make the iBus indicator go away and not confuse me.
Can I do this (hopefully without hurting other usage scenario, like logging in to a different desktop environment)?

Imperfect solution:

Execute ibus-setup
In the dialog which comes up, untoggle "Show icon on system tray"
Press Close

That makes the ibus indicator go away... always. So if you now switch to another desktop environment which does not provide its own indicator, you'll need to change the setup again.
